# facebook open graph, post to timeline/wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I created an action type, object type and aggregation. Action type is not approval yet. But it's work on my developer account. I'm publish an action by using the code below. It success and I can view an aggregation in my timeline. But It does not post anything on timeline/wall. How I can publish an action on timeline/wall?

```
FB.api(
        '/me/mynamespace:myaction?myobject=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        'post',
        function(response) {
            if (response && response.error) {
                alert(response.error.message);
            }else if(!response){
                alert('Error');
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable explicit sharing.

Click on the action type and enable explicit sharing as shown below.

Then you need to submit the action for approval.

[image]

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/submission-process/opengraph/guidelines/action-properties/#explicitlyshared